# No auto-fill for logins that are split into login first password second

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed that auto fill doesn't work for websites that don't show username and password fields on the same page. I need to fill login manually, hit next then password field is filled already. On the websites that login and password fields are on the same steps, auto fill is working without any issues. Chrome is on windows 11 the latest stable release. Is anything I could do with that?